# Excel, linked WorkSheets causing "0" to appear in blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project which involves 14 sales consultants each with a client pipeline. These 14 sheets are in a Workbook (`Workbook A`) that has 1 Sheet to consolidate all the information into one pipeline.
Each consultant has an individual WorkBook that they fill in and the information is then actively transferred to `Workbook A` from their individual Workbook Sheets.

The problem I have is that I used a direct link (`=Sheet1`), because of this method I used I have to set the amount of cells to link.
All the cells I have linked with no information returns a zero in `Workbook A` which then causes my Consolidation page to bring in all the rows with "0" in and it does not look nice.

I would like to prevent the Consolidation sheet to import these 0 figures from the consultant sheets.

[image: Workbook Screenshot]

This information is constantly being refreshed so the filter also gets refreshed which means I cannot simply hide it by deselecting the value on the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using a `=isblank` formula to prevent the blank cells from causing you to see the 0's.

Something like this maybe `=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!'YOURCELLSHERE),'','Sheet1!Cell')`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Sometimes the most simple things are made complicated when you don't see a solution straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File|Options|Advanced and scroll down to "display options for this worksheet" and un-check "Show a zero in cells that have zero value".   Keep in mind that this will cause cells that should display a "0" to not display that "0".

Comment: Hi Thank you for trying to assist. I have tried that but unfortunately I have cells with the value "0" and need some areas to display a "0". Jacob's answer solved my problem.